After Vue build, get an unexpected token error '??' in web browser
Built a Vue application in Visual Studio using Typescript. Ran the build command for production to get the compiled Javascript file. When I run the script in a browser, I get a syntax error for an unexpected token '??'. The '??' only appears in the output file and not in the Typescript code. The nullish coalescing operator is valid Javascript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing
example from the Vue generated Javascript file
(n ?? (n = e.get(i) === i._trackId))

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this. Suggestions?
EDIT:
Here is the error. The error occurs in Chrome and Edge.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??'

RESOLUTION:
I compiled the Vue application in Visual Studio Code and added that Javascript file to my project and the error does not occur anymore.
The difference between the two being Visual Studio 2022 is using Vue 3.5.12 and Visual Studio Code is using Vue 3.4.29.

Please, list the error instead of describing it. What's browser and version? Did you try it in another one? The syntax is ok and it has been supported by browsers for several years, as it's seen in the docs. You can change TS target to transpile the operator in case it's a problem for some reason. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce.
